# How do I change just one column name to lowercase and leave the others as they are?

Tags: r

I have two data frames and wish to combine them (this information is merely to provide context and doesn't form part of my question).

They share a common field, `SpecimenID` in `df1`, and `specimenid` in `df2`, which I wish to convert to lower so that I can populate that field with both dataframes' specimen numbers when combined.

The other column names should remain as they are.

My question: How can I convert a single column name to lowercase and leave the others in their present form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename(specimenid = SpecimenID)
```

This will change `SpecimenID` to `specimenid`.

If your ultimate goal is to merge the two dataframes then you don't need to rename the column names since join can be performed on columns which are of different names.

Comment: Yes, I am going to join the data frames and aware of the `by = c("specimenid" = "SpecimenID")` statement, but it got me thinking how I can change just one column name to lowercase. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's converting one column name with `tolower` (suppose it was a very long column name and you didn't want to manually type the lowercase replacement):

```
names(df1)[which(names(df1) == "SpecimenID")] <- tolower("SpecimenID")
```